# Getting the link of a release uploaded using upload_to_play_store

Tags: android, fastlane, fastfile

I'm using Fastlane's **upload_to_play_store** to send **.aab** files to the internal testing track on Google Play Store, and I'm looking for a way to get a shareable link of the bundles I upload.

Is there a Fastlane function that will help me to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a non-official way (workaround) to get a shareable link which is **manually constructing the URL**.

The shareable link must follow the format:

[https://play.google.com/apps/test/{app_package_name}/{version_code}](https://play.google.com/apps/test/%7Bapp_package_name%7D/%7Bversion_code%7D)

**{app_package_name}**: The package name of the uploaded bundle / apk

**{version_code}**: The version code of the same bundle / apk

The link will be something like this:

https://play.google.com/apps/test/com.example.app/762